# WKInterfaceButton simultaneous push segue and action

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard, watchkit

Why is it that when a `WKInterfaceButton` is connected to both a push segue and an action, the action isn't called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a segue, the old InterfaceController goes off screen, of course. WatchOS seems to destroy the bridge between your extension and the App (the storyboard/interface). The same thing happens in the other direction. The extension can't modify UIs that aren't on screen. An example is UI properties. Try setting the color of a label after the interface controller goes off screen. It won't work.

From the docs:

> Important
>
> An interface controller can make changes to its interface only during initialization and when the interface is active. Once the didDeactivate() method is called, any attempts to change the value of related interface objects are ignored until the interface controller’s willActivate() method is called again.

Presumably you're an iOS dev. It might be good to read through https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller

Since I started learning watchOS, a lot of my assumptions/experience did not translate well over to the watch.